# Not able to exclude some java packages from local server analysis

Tags: sonarqube

We have upgarded sonar server 3.5.1. In order to use sonar I have upgraded my local eclipse to Juno(4.2) and sonar plugin to 3.1. Sonar server is able to exclude some packages usign sonar.excustions key and does not show violations for those packages. But when I run report for sonar local analysis I see even though I added sonar.exclusions from local properties it does show violations for exluded files. How i can resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.
Sapana.

Answer (score 0):

There's currently a limitation on Sonar side (see http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/SONAR-4265) that prevents modules to retrieve all their related settings when analyzed independently from their root project.

Feel free to watch and vote for the ticket.